# Line chart series drilldown to another linechart series

Tags: javascript, highcharts, linechart, series, drilldown

http://jsfiddle.net/4kp2bdus/3/

I've been trying to get this highcharts example to work where if I click on each of the lines, you can then drill down into it's own new line chart series.

So each one of the lines is a competency and I want to be able to drill down do each competency's Behavior that has relatively the same type of data.

I tried having Foundation behaviors as one of the drilldowns but it did not work.

Thanks for you help!

```js
// Internationalization


$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Competency Trend',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Max Score: 4'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        drilldown: {
          series: []
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Foundation',
            data: [2.0, 2.3, 2.5, 2.9, 3.0, 2.6, 2.8, 2.65, 2.7, 2.67, 2.9, 3.0],
            drilldown: 'foundationBehaviors'
        }, {
            name: 'Build Value',
            data: [2.9, 2.9, 2.9, 2.875, 2.8, 3.0, 2.9, 2.8, 3.1, 3.2, 3.30, 3.29]
        }, {
            name: 'Discover',
            data: [3.0, 3.1, 3.3, 3.1, 3.4, 3.42, 3.5, 3.55, 3.59, 3.61, 3.66, 3.71]
        }, {
            name: 'Advance',
            data: [3.3, 3.4, 3.45, 3.6, 3.62, 3.65, 3.69, 3.71, 3.8, 3.89, 3.76, 3.8]
        }, {
            name: 'Engage',
            data: [3.5, 3.51, 3.45, 3.7, 4.0, 3.76, 3.8, 3.95, 4.0, 4.0, 3.9, 3.86]
        }, {
            id: 'foundationBehaviors',
            name: 'Foundation Behaviors',
            categories: ['Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug'],
            data: [3.5, 3.51, 3.45, 3.7, 4.0, 3.76, 3.8, 3.95, 4.0, 4.0, 3.9, 3.86]
        }],
        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drilldown is associated with a `point` not with a `series`.  And, the series that you drill down to is defined in the `drilldown` member, not in the normal `series` member.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/drilldown

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: 'Competency Trend',
      x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: '',
      x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug']
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Max Score: 4'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ''
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    drilldown: {
      series: [{
        id: 'foundationBehaviors',
        name: 'Foundation Behaviors',
        categories: ['Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug'],
        data: [3.5, 3.51, 3.45, 3.7, 4.0, 3.76, 3.8, 3.95, 4.0, 4.0, 3.9, 3.86]
      }]
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Foundation',
      data: [{y:2.0, drilldown: 'foundationBehaviors'}, 2.3, 2.5, 2.9, 3.0, 2.6, 2.8, 2.65, 2.7, 2.67, 2.9, 3.0]
    }, {
      name: 'Build Value',
      data: [2.9, 2.9, 2.9, 2.875, 2.8, 3.0, 2.9, 2.8, 3.1, 3.2, 3.30, 3.29]
    }, {
      name: 'Discover',
      data: [3.0, 3.1, 3.3, 3.1, 3.4, 3.42, 3.5, 3.55, 3.59, 3.61, 3.66, 3.71]
    }, {
      name: 'Advance',
      data: [3.3, 3.4, 3.45, 3.6, 3.62, 3.65, 3.69, 3.71, 3.8, 3.89, 3.76, 3.8]
    }, {
      name: 'Engage',
      data: [3.5, 3.51, 3.45, 3.7, 4.0, 3.76, 3.8, 3.95, 4.0, 4.0, 3.9, 3.86]
    }],

  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4kp2bdus/4/

Comment: hi ... how to do this dynamically ... i mean every time i pass the list (generated by data in db or etc) so this solution works if simply insert the numbers inside the code itself not by passing list or any var..

Comment: @RouzbehZarandi You can replace the hardcoded arrays with variables.  You might want to create a new question with your code and what specific problems you are having with it.